# ASP.NET autocomplete not respected by Google Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, autocomplete

I'm using the following ASP.NET code to make my input box not to use autocomplete:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxID" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

It works with Microsoft's own IE, but Google Chrome still allows autocomplete on it. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe its just a broswer setting.

Comment: try using autocomplete="off"

Comment: @ShafqatMasood: If I'm not mistaking `autocomplete="off"` is not a valid ASP.NET tag, but it works. In IE though I get `autocomplete="off"` twice in a final rendered HTML 'input' tag...

Answer (score 1):

For Chrome the `autocomplete="off"` specification has to be placed on the `form` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Recent Version of Google Chrome forces Autofill irrespective of the `Autocomplete=off`.Some of the previous hacks don't work anymore (34+ versions)

I have tested following code on Google Chrome v36.

**Solution 1:**
Putting 2 lines of code under under `<form ..>` tag does the trick.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" >
<input style="display:none" type="text" name="fakeusernameremembered"/>
<input style="display:none" type="password" name="fakepasswordremembered"/>

...
```

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

**Solution 2:**
It removes "name" and "id" attributes from elements and assigns them back after 1ms. Put this in `document get ready`.

```
$('form[autocomplete="off"] input, input[autocomplete="off"]').each(function () {

                var input = this;
                var name = $(input).attr('name');
                var id = $(input).attr('id');

                $(input).removeAttr('name');
                $(input).removeAttr('id');

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(input).attr('name', name);
                    $(input).attr('id', id);
                }, 1);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing autocomplete=off in the form tag does not work anymore. Google ignores it.

I have solved the issue by renaming my textboxes. Do not use in the name anything that google can get hint to autocomplete it like (name,address,postalcode,etc..). I have changed txtName to txtN and autcomplete stopped.

If this does not work, place autocomplete="new-name" directly in the property of the textbox not on the form.

```
<asp:TextBox autocomplete="new-name" ID="txtName"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```